# Android application - reading all mp3 tags

Tags: java, android, tags, mp3

As I see at MediaMetadataRetriever API, there are constants for the common tags.
In my app I want to read all the mp3 tags. In order to do this I use jid3lib.
When I tried to read tags without any connection to android (MP3 files on my computer), I succeeded, but when I tried to read MP3 files on the emulator my application crashed.

I pushed some music files into the emulator, and I succeeded in reading these files names, but when the application is trying to get the tags it crashed.

I wonder if there is any android permission that I have to declare in the manifest? Or maybe there is difference between reading files on the local computer and in android? because I use the same logic to read MP3 files on my computer and it works.

**EDIT : Code from comment below for better readability**

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC); 
File[] songs = path.listFiles(); 
for (int i=0; i<songs.length; i++){ 
   try { 
      MusicFile song = new MusicFile(songs[i]); 
      Log.d("VanVan", song.getArtist()); 
   } catch (TagException e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Did you create the folder that holds the MP3 files using Eclipse, or did you just navigate to a folder in your local system and created it? This is because sometimes Eclipse doesn't notice that you created a folder on your local system even if you reference it correctly. Try creating the folder using Eclipse and drag the files to it.

Comment: The files are located at:
mnt\sdcard\Music (on the emulator)

I use the following code:
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
File[] songs = path.listFiles();

  for (int i=0; i<songs.length; i++){

   
try {
   MusicFile song = new MusicFile(songs[i]);
   Log.d("VanVan", song.getArtist());
} catch (TagException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}

While the MusicFile type is private class which I created that uses jid3lib and works good for mp3 files on my computer